# removing extra jars dependencies from java project

Tags: maven, maven-plugin

I am working on migrating multi module java project into maven. Now for most of them i migrated to maven.
Finally i am aware my project have lot of unnecessary jars included, and i want to clean them up.

I know maven has plugin command, **mvn dependency:analyze**. Which works very well.

dependency:analyze analyzes the dependencies of this project and determines which are: used and declared; used and undeclared; unused and declared. based on static code analysis.

**Now my question** is that, how can i remove reported unused and declared dependency for cleanup purpose. It could be possible those jars were getting used at runtime and my code will compile perfectly fine after removing but blow up at runtime.

**An example:** mycode compile with one of opensource library antisamy.jar but it require batik.jar at runtime. And mvn dependency:analyze reports me to remove batik.jar.

IS my understanding correct or i need expert inputs here.

Comment: Please use version specific tags wisely. If you have a general problem, use the general tag without version

Answer (score 0):

Your understanding seems to be correct.
But I'm not sure why you'd think that there is a tool that could cover all the bases.
Yes, if you use stuff by reflection, no tool can reliably detect the fact that you depend on this class or the other.

For example consider this snippet:

```
String myClassName = "com." + "example." + "SomeClass";
Class.forName(myClassName);
```

I don't think you can build a tool that can crawl through the code and extract all such references.

I'd use a try-and-fail approach instead, which would consist of:

- remove all dependencies that `dependency:analyze` says are superfluous
- whenever you find one that was actually used, you just add it back

This could work well because I expect that the number of dependencies that are actually used by reflection to be extremely small.

Comment: There are certain libraries which add optional support for functionality based on the existence of a library on the classpath or not, especially in web environments. Its not only reflective logic but also just classpath scanning that can be severely influenced here.

Comment: Agreed; my bet was however that in most applications these corner cases happen pretty rarely, and therefore the try-and-fail approach works okish (especially since any error should be pretty visible, quickly).